# Comparar dois arquivos utilizando Shellscript

Tags: shell-script

Tenho uma série de coletores de dados conectados à um serviço. Este serviço é provido por terceiros e eu não possuo acesso "admin" para criar as consultas conforme meu interesse. A unica forma de saber se estes coletores estão ativos é via uma URL que me retorna um texto puro com os endereços IP dos equipamentos:

```
["/10.0.0.110","/10.0.0.119","/10.0.0.130","/10.0.0.114"/10.0.0.110","/10.0.0.119"]
```

Este formato é ruim para o usuário final, muitas vezes vem endereços duplicados, precisaria de algo mais amigável (eu tenho 20 desses, se tiver um desconectado, fica péssimo para identificar e não quero ficar amarrado a esta tarefa de verificar)

Consegui tratar o "arquivo1" para ficar desta forma (Valores únicos e sequenciais)

```
10.0.0.110
10.0.0.113
10.0.0.119
10.0.0.130
```

Porém, como sabemos usuários tendem a apresentar certa preguiça para relacionar os números. 
Tenho uma "tabela2" com os seguintes dados:

```
10.0.0.110 ---> coletor A
[...]
10.0.0.130 ---> coletor R
```

Gostaria de alguma sugestão para comparar as ocorrências no arquivo1 e tabela2. O retorno esperado seria algo do tipo:

```
10.0.0.110 --> coletor A
10.0.0.113 --> coletor D
10.0.0.119 --> coletor H
10.0.0.130 --> coletor R
```

Desde já agradeço.

Consegui resolver com a dica do amigo @JJoao.

```
$join arquivo1 tabela2 > combinados
```

O "join" necessita que os arquivos estejam ordenados em ordem crescente. Para isso utilize:

```
$cat arquivo |sort |uniq > arquivo1
```

Comment: Não li a fundo, então posso estar me enganando. Já tentou ver o comando `diff`? Para comparar dois arquivos?

Comment: experimenta `join file1 tabela2` supondo que ambos estão ordenados.

Comment: @JJoao, Obrigado! Funcionou do jeito que eu precisava.

Comment: Poderia, por favor, criar uma resposta com a solução encontrada? Deixá-la na pergunta faz com que ela fique erroneamente sem resposta. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue a resposta para a solução do problema. Consegui resolver utilizando a dica que o @JJoao deu: 
O "join" necessita que os arquivos estejam ordenados em ordem crescente. Para isso utilize:

```
$cat arquivo |sort |uniq > arquivo1
```

Exemplo de utilização do comando "join":

```
$join arquivo1 tabela2 > combinados
```

> $man join
>
> join - join lines of two files on a common field
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          join [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2
>
> DESCRIPTION For  each  pair of input lines with identical join fields,
>   write a line to standard output.  The default join field is the first,
>   delimited  by whitespace.  When FILE1 or FILE2 (not both) is -, read
>   standard input.